# Checking if combination of any amount of strings exists

Tags: javascript

I'm solving a puzzle and I have an idea of how to solve this problem, but I would like some guidance and hints.

Suppose I have the following, Given n amount of words to input, and m amount of word combos without spaces, I will have some functionality as the following.

```
    4
    this
    is
    my
    dog
    5
    thisis        // outputs 1
    thisisacat    // 0, since a or cat wasnt in the four words
    thisisaduck   // 0, no a or cat
    thisismy      // 1 this,is,my is amoung the four words
    thisismydog   // 1
```

**My thoughts**

First What I was thinking of doing is storing those first words into an array. After that, I check if any of those words is the first word of those 5 words

**Example:** check if `this` is in the first word `thisis`. It is! Great, now remove that `this`, from `thisis` to get simply just `is`, now delete the original string that corresponded to that equality and keep iterating over the left overs (now `is,my,dog` are available). If we can keep doing this process, until we get an empty string. We return 1, else return 0!

Are my thoughts on the right track? I think this would be a good approach (By the way I would like to implement this in javascript)

Comment: I'd check from longest target word to shortest ... I mean 'a' appears in many words

Comment: The difficult case is when you have input like: `3 bite bit every 2 bitevery biteevery` . Your solution needs to realise that even though a word starts with `bite` it might also start with `bit` and might need the e for the next word.

Comment: Hmm. How should I start? By sorting? Should I sort the first four words or what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting words from long to short may in some cases help to find a solution quicker, but it is not a guarantee. Sentences that contain the longest word might only have a solution if that longest word is *not* used.

Take for instance this test case:

**Words**: toolbox, stool, boxer
**Sentence:** stoolboxer

If "toolbox" is taken as a word in that sentence, then the remaining characters cannot be matched with other valid words. Yet, there is a solution, but only if the word "toolbox" is not used.

#### Solution with a Regular Expression

When regular expressions are allowed as part of the solution, then it is quite simple. For the above example, the regular expression would be:

```
^(toolbox|stool|boxer)*$
```

If a sentence matches that expression, it is a solution. If not, then not. This is quite straightforward, and doesn't really require an algorithm. All is done by the regular expression interpreter. Here is a snippet:

```js
var words = ['this','is','a','string'];
var sentences = ['thisis','thisisastring','thisisaduck','thisisastringg','stringg']; 

var regex = new RegExp('^(' + words.join('|') + ')*$');
sentences.forEach(sentence => {
    // search returns a position. It should be 0:
    console.log(sentence + ': ' + (sentence.search(regex) ? 'No' : 'Yes'));
});
```

But using regular expressions in an algorithm-challenge feels like cheating: you don't really write the algorithm, but rely on the regular expression implementation to do the job for you.

#### Without Regular Expressions

You could use this algorithm: first check whether a word matches at the start of the input sentence, and if so, remove that first occurrence from it. Then repeat this for the remaining part of the sentence. If this can be repeated until no characters are left over, you have a solution.

If characters are left over which cannot be matched with any word... well, then you cannot really conclude there is no solution for that sentence. It might be that some earlier made word choice was the wrong one, and there was an alternative. So to cope with that, your algorithm could backtrack and try other words.

This principle can be implemented through recursion. To gain memory-efficiency, you could leave the original sentence in-tact, and work with an index in that sentence instead.

The algorithm is implemented in arrow-function `testString`:

```js
var words = ['this','is','a','string'];
var sentences = ['thisis','thisisastring','thisisaduck','thisisastringg','stringg']; 

var testString = (words, str, i = 0) =>
    i >= str.length || words.some( word =>
        str.substr(i, word.length) == word && testString(words, str, i + word.length)
    );
    
sentences.forEach(sentence => {
    console.log(sentence + ': ' + (testString(words, sentence) ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
});
```

Or, the same in non-arrow-function syntax:

```js
var words = ['this','is','a','string'];
var sentences = ['thisis','thisisastring','thisisaduck','thisisastringg','stringg']; 

var testString = function (words, str, i = 0) {
    return i >= str.length || words.some(function (word) {
        return str.substr(i, word.length) == word 
            && testString(words, str, i + word.length);
    });
}
sentences.forEach(function (sentence) {
    console.log(sentence + ': ' + (testString(words, sentence) ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
});
```

... and without `some()`, `forEach()` or ternary operator:

```js
var words = ['this','is','a','string'];
var sentences = ['thisis','thisisastring','thisisaduck','thisisastringg','stringg']; 

function testString (words, str, i = 0) {
    if (i >= str.length) return true;
    for (var k = 0; k < words.length; k++) {
         var word = words[k];
         if (str.substr(i, word.length) == word 
             && testString(words, str, i + word.length)) {
              return true;
         }
    }
}

for (var n = 0; n < sentences.length; n++) {
    var sentence = sentences[n];
    if (testString(words, sentence)) {
        console.log(sentence + ': Yes');
    } else {
        console.log(sentence + ': No');
    }
}
```

Comment: Great first solution, very unique. Could you point me to where I can learn about setting a variable to something in brackets like var testString = (words, str, i = 0), sorry I haven't seen anything like that before, setting a variable to something in brackets. Thanks for answering my question as usual by the way :)

Comment: the syntax `var testString = (words, str, i = 0)` is only the first part of an arrow function. The bracketed part lists the arguments of the function, like in this alternative syntax: `var testString = function (words, str, i = 0) {` ... etc.

Comment: I added the last code block again in a version that does not use arrow-functions. It might be interesting to compare the syntax.

Comment: the second one has an arrow after return i as well btw. Thanks im gonna write this down and trace the program

Comment: Haha I've been playing around with the console and trying to write down the iterations on a piece of paper and I think I have an idea of how this works, I'd just like to confirm something later with you about the code on chat, I have to go to bed now though. Talk to you later :)

Comment: Holy... I get it, THIS WASN'T EVEN HARD!! I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Is it important I starting using => in my code? As you can see I always get confused when people use it, even though it doesent seem that hard. The only reason I don't like using the ecmascript stuff is that it doesent work on all browsers. Of course im talking about ecmascript stuff in general

Answer (score 1):

Take the 4 words, put them into a regex.
Use that regex to split each string.
Take the length of the resulting array (subtract one for the initial length of one).

```
var size = 'thisis'.split(/this|is|my|dog/).length - 1
```

Or if your list of words is an array

```
var search = new RegExp(words.join('|'))
var size = 'thisis'.split(search).length - 1
```

Either way you are splitting up the string by the list of words you have defined.

---

You can sort the words by length to ensure that larger words are matched first by

```
words.sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length })
```

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: Why does he get downvoted for trying to help with his own opinion?

Comment: jfi: it was not me :-S

Comment: @choz I have no idea, but I thought his solution was fine, so I upvoted it.  I really like his `split` strategy.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why does it matter if we sort larger words first or smaller ones first?

Comment: Although I don't see it in what op asked, it would in theory match more of each individual string by matching larger words first.

Comment: @kamoroso94 The answer isn't helpful. It doesn't attempt to solve the OP's problem of deciding whether or not the input contains only the words that are in the string. It could be adjusted by checking if the result of the split is an array of empty strings, but even then it would have the same problem as cstuncsik's answer, the regex will match the first word that matches, so if you use `'/bite|bit|every/` it won't decide `bitevery` correctly, because the regex will match `bite` but not `very`, when it should have matched `bit` and `every`. Sorting doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for anyone interested

```
var input = ['this','is','a','string']; // This will work for any input, but this is a test case
var orderedInput = input.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.length - a.length;
});
var inputRegex = new RegExp(orderedInput.join('|'));
// our combonation of words can be any size in an array, just doin this since prompt in js is spammy
var testStrings = ['thisis','thisisastring','thisisaduck','thisisastringg','stringg']; 
var foundCombos  = (regex,str) => !str.split(regex).filter(str => str.length).length;
var finalResult = testStrings.reduce((all,str)=>{
    all[str] = foundCombos(inputRegex,str);
    if (all[str] === true){
        all[str] = 1;
    }
    else{
        all[str] = 0;
    }
    return all;
},{});
console.log(finalResult);
```